# Обработка данных в режиме реального времени в print()

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть функция `status` которая показывает статус моей программы(оно еще не доработано) и есть функция, которая каждый раз обновляет список.

После прохода всех функций, он запускает все заново, и мне нужно, чтобы он обновлял данные `company_list`, если вдруг там поменялось количество компаний.
Это в принципе осуществимо, но он каждый раз выводит принты на новой строке, а я хочу сделать так, чтобы оно на той же строке обновилось, как это можно осуществить?

Пытался использовать каретку `\r` в принте, но это не то, в интернете информации никакой не нашел...

```
def status():
    print('Status: ' + 'ONLINE')
    print('Количество: ', str(len(company_list)))
```

Comment: Вам как я понял нужен динамический вывод: [Возможно это ответ на ваш вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122385/dynamic-terminal-printing-with-python)

Comment: Да, динамический, чтобы на одной строке был статус и висел там и обновлялся в зависимости от изменений)

Comment: С помощью библиотеки `curses` можно такие штуки творить. https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, сейчас пойду изучать и пытаться сделать!)

Comment: Посмотрите ещё модуль `tqdm`.

Answer (score 0):

> я хочу сделать так, чтобы оно на той же строке обновилось, как это
>   можно осуществить?

Если Вы хотите запретить перевод строки после печати, то сделайте так:

```
print("Без перевода строки", end=' ')
```

По умолчанию, параметр *end='\n'*, т.е. перевод строки. Задайте в качестве завершителя символ пробела и перевода строки не будет.

Comment: Модуль «curses» решил мою проблему. Хотел именно консоль, которая обновляет вывод в консоли:)